# What is the difference between 'python-shell-send-buffer' and 'python-execute-file'?

Tags: python

I have had difficulties to run any python code when using `python-execute-file` (`SPC m c c` in spacemacs), until I finally found out that I have to use `python-shell-send-buffer` (`SPC m s b` in Spacemacs) to run code.

I wonder what is the purpose of `python-execute-file` then?

Comment: I don't think there is a `python-execute-file` function in python mode, but [Spacemacs seems to have a function](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/bd7ef98e4c35fd87538dd2a81356cc83f5fd02f3/layers/%2Blang/python/packages.el) with a similar name: `spacemacs/python-execute-file`.

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, in vanilla emacs, I cannot find `python-execute-file`, but looks like it is similar to `python-shell-send-file` in stock emacs.

- `python-shell-send-file` (bound by default to `C-c C-l`) prompts the user to select the file they want to send to the `python-shell-interpreter` (default value is `"python"`).. it need not be the current file or one of the open Python files.
- `python-shell-send-buffer` (bound by default to `C-c C-c`) sends the **current** buffer to the `python-shell-interpreter` without asking any questions.

So if you want to quickly want to *evaluate* the script you are currently working on, you would use `python-shell-send-buffer`. But if you want to evaluation some other file (already open or not), you would use `python-shell-send-file` (or may be `python-execute-file`).

Comment: I think it's something different. It sais: `spacemacs/python-execute-file is an interactive Lisp function. [...] Execute a python script in a shell.`

Comment: Is it possible to send only a highlighted region of a buffer?

Comment: @fraxture Yes, you can use `python-shell-send-region` which is bound to `C-c C-r` by default.